Should I send an email to the editor-in-chief regarding the delay in receiving the editor's decision for my submitted research paper?
I submitted my research paper to a Springer journal called Electrical Engineering a few months ago. After exactly three months, I received a major revision, and the editor gave me 14 days to send back a revised version of the manuscript and a point-by-point response to a reviewer’s concerns. I sent what he asked for within the recommended timeline.
It’s been a month and five days, and I still haven’t received the editor’s decision. Although the status is peer review and Your submission has passed technical checks as of 06 Mar 24, the editors’ decision can take several weeks as they may consult peer reviewers. I have sent an email to the journal’s editorial-office assistant to inquire about this, but she keeps copying and pasting the same response, stating that I have to wait for the editor’s decision.
Now, Should I send an email to the editor-in-chief, or it is not recommended?

You should stop emailing them and wait at least another few months. The following is a huge red flag:

I have sent an email to the Journal's Editorial Office Assistant to inquire about this, but she keeps copying and pasting the same response, stating that I have to wait for the editor's decision.

Even though they ask you to respond on a fast timeline, they cannot similarly force the reviewer to respond immediately, and you are certainly not in a position to force the editor or reviewer to act on such a fast timeline. After your revisions, the paper would go back to reviewer 1, who is probably some overworked professor in the busiest time of the academic year. They will hopefully look at the revisions over the summer. If you keep emailing the editor, office assistant, and editor in chief, you will alienate them. Since it took 3 months to hear back the first time, I think you could check in after 3 months again. But please do so tactfully and recognizing that the people you're emailing are doing their best.  As an author, I once waited 18 months for a first referee report. I once had a positive referee report, made all the changes they requested, and had to wait 9 months for the editor to accept the paper. Waiting is completely normal at this stage of the publication process, so please find a way to wait.

Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I will wait a bit longer, but as a PhD student, publishing my first research paper is mandatory for defending my thesis. That's why I'm feeling a bit rushed.

@Gomasha if it got to the point where the delay was hampering your ability to graduate, then your advisor could write to the editor and try to smoothly get the paper unstuck. But, I'd only use that in case of emergency. Waiting is the better option.

Without wishing to seem unkind: the fact that your thesis defense is contingent on getting this paper published is not the journal's problem.  Your school has decided to outsource (part of) their assessment process by getting the editor to do it for free.
